# The program doesn't stop on scanf("%c", &ch) line, why?

Tags: c

the program doesnt stop on scanf("%c", &ch) line. why does it happens sombody can please explain this to me

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct list {
   char val;
   struct list * next;
};

typedef struct list item;

void main()
{
    char ch;
    int num;

    printf("Enter [1] if you want to use linked list or [2] for realloc\n");  
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if(num == 2)
    {
        scanf("%c", &ch); 
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, while just about every other format specifier for `scanf` strips leading whitespace, `%c` is the oddball. You have to treat it very gingerly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's say you input 2 when you're reading for num. The actual input stream will be 2\n (\n is the newline character). 2 goes into the num, and there remains \n, which goes into ch. To avoid this, add a whitespace in format specifier.

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

This will ignore any whitespaces, newlines or tabs.

Answer (score 9):

The reason behind this is the newline `\n` character left behind by previous `scanf`, when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, for the next read of `scanf`. When the statement

```
scanf("%c", &ch);
```

executed then it reads that `\n` left behind by the previous `scanf`.
To eat up this `\n` you can use a space before `%c` specifier. A space before the `%c` specifier is able to eat up any number of white-space characters.

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);   
       ^ a space
```