# Why this C scanf is automatically skipped?

Tags: c

I am facing problem regarding `scanf` in C. When I run this:

```
char c;
int a, b;

scanf("%d", &a);
scanf("%c", &c);
scanf("%d", &b);
```

Then first two `scanf` were working properly but 3rd one is skipped completely. I searched different posts in this forum about this problem and found a lot of information, but want to know something else.

I already found that the easiest solution would be:

```
scanf("%d %c %d", &a, &c, &b);
```

And another solution could be using:

```
getchar();
```

And I also found that the reason behind my problem is it writes an extra new line character `\n` to the buffer, that's why the 3rd one was skipped. But for further researching I found that when I use another `scanf` of `char` type after 2nd `scanf` then it works. That means, in my case the problem occurs if I take input of any `integer` type after `char` type. Again I have seen many others were problem having opposite case, they couldn't take input of `char` after `integer`. Now I want to be clarified about the exact schemes those are supported in C for `scanf` that is when I will face similar problems and why `char` can be scanned after `char` but `integer` can't. Thanks to all.

Comment: I don;t think you have the problem the way you say it..... the other one which the others are having is the actual problem.

Comment: scanf is never skipped.   To find out what the result of your scanf was, check its return value.

Comment: To get help with a specific piece of code, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also specify exactly what input you typed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306659/the-program-doesnt-stop-on-scanfc-ch-line-why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `"%d"` format specifier includes skipping leading white-space. The `"%c"` format doesn't have that, it reads the next character in the input buffer no matter what kind of character it is.

If you want to skip leading white-space using the `"%c"` format, you need to tell `scanf` explicitly to do so with a space in the format string, like e.g. `" %c"`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same problem as "not able to take `char` after an `int`", with a small twist.

Recall that when you read an `int` from an input using `scanf` with `%d` format specifier, the characters representing the number are consumed, but the separator following it is not. Consider a buffer that looks like this (I use underscores to show spaces):

```
char     9 8 _ x _ 7 6
         - - - - - - -
position 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

- Before the first `scanf` call your buffer is positioned at zero.
- After the first call your buffer is positioned at 2.
- After the second call your buffer is positioned at 3, because space is read for your `char`

Now the problem becomes clear: the third `scanf` tries to read an `int`, but the buffer is at `x`, so the read is not possible.