# Issue clearing input stream in C

Tags: c, buffer, fflush

I've recently started learning C, and while trying to make a simple calculator, I encountered an issue while trying to clear the input stream. I tried using `fflush(stdin);` but apparently, it didn't do anything.

> Operating System: macOS Sierra (Version 10.12.5 (16F73))
>
> Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
>
> Editor Used: Sublime Text 3

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    char opr;
    char choice = 'y';

    while (choice == 'y') {
        printf("Enter numbers separated with a comma: \n");
        scanf("%d, %d", &num1, &num2);

        printf("Enter an operator: \n");
        fflush (stdin);
        scanf("%c", &opr);

        switch (opr) {
            case '+':
                printf("The sum is %ld\n", (long int) num1 + num2);
                break;
            case '-':
                printf("The difference is %ld\n", (long int) num1 - num2);
                break;
            case '*':
                printf("The product is %ld\n", (long int) num1 * num2);
                break;
            case '/':
                printf("The quotient is %ld and the remainder is %ld\n",
                    (long int) num1 / num2, (long int) num1 % num2);
                break;
            default:
                printf("You've entered an undefined operator\n");
                printf("Please enter + - * or /\n");
                break;
        }

        printf("Do you want to repeat? (y/n):  \n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the terminal output:

```
$ ./calculator_basic
Enter numbers separated with a comma:
20, 30
Enter an operator:
You've entered an undefined operator
Please enter + - * or /
Do you want to repeat? (y/n):
n
```

---

An easy solution that I found out was to simply interchange the places of

```
printf("Enter numbers separated with a comma: \n");<br>
scanf("%d, %d", &num1, &num2);
```

and

```
printf("Enter an operator: \n");
fflush (stdin);
scanf("%c", &opr);
```

---

I understand that the problem is due to the *enter* key being stored in the input buffer after entering the numbers in `scanf("%d, %d", &num1, &num2);`
and `scanf("%c", &opr);` then uses this stored *enter* key (in the buffer) as its input which creates the problem (ie: none of the cases in `switch` defined by me work and the default case runs, all this without even me being able to enter an operator)

I tried using `fflush(stdin);` before getting new character inputs but it doesn't seem to work.

The thing is that `fflush(stdin);` is working when I'm trying to run this code in a Windows system, but it's not working on macOS regardless of the editor I'm using (tried both Sublime Text 3 and Visual Studio Code)

Can anyone help me out regarding why `fflush(stdin);` might not be working.
Also I've read about it on the internet and one solution was to use `cin.get();` instead of `getchar();`. I tried it but this didn't work as well. I don't want to interchange those two pieces of codes (mentioned above) because that would be hit and trial. I want to run the code in the same order (entering the numbers first and then the operator)

Also, I know questions on `fflush(stdin)` have been asked previously, but I've read the answers and can't seem to figure out anything that works for me.

Comment: I don't see any question in there. I also don't understand why you would use `fflush(stdin)`. Did some documentation tell you that would do something that would be helpful to you or did you just make it up? If the former, can you link to the documentation? (Short answer: If you want to read a *line* and then parse it, write code to do that.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz My instructor told me to use `fflush(stdin)` and it seems to work fine on her system.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Also, I've edited the question. Please have a look and let me know if i'm still not clear

Comment: @HarshitJindal "My instructor told me to use fflush(stdin)" + "fflush(stdin); is undefined behavior." --> `flush(instructor)`.

Comment: @HarshitJindal If that's typical of how your instructor determines that things are safe and reliable, you need a new instructor. Code that "just happens to work when I tried it" often later happens not to work when someone else relies on it.

Comment: don't edit your question once it has been answered.

Comment: `scanf("%c", &opr);` --> `scanf(" %c", &opr);`  Add space.

Comment: @Binary_10 I didn't. I just added a tag which was somehow left when I originally wrote the question

Comment: Adding the space worked. Thank you so much. Could you please post it as a solution so that I could mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: This is really a dupe of many post like [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20306692/2410359)

Comment: @HarshitJindal to avoid some very common errors, you might want to read my [document on `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Newline character**

To remove the (only) newline character (`'\n'`) left in buffer, introduce a `space` `(' ')` in the format string of `scanf()`. This directive matches with any no of white spaces (even `zero`).

```
scanf(" %c", &opr);
```

or you could just use `getchar()` to read `'\n'` whenever needed, thus leaving the buffer with **no** characters.

Now the code will work properly as long as you enter the input correctly.

If there's more than a single character left in the buffer (for any reason), use the following code to flush i/p stream.

**Flushing `stdin`**

To flush the input stream try one of the following ways.

```
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
    getchar();
```

or

```
    int ch;
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

use it only when you are certain that the buffer isn't empty otherwise in either case the code expects/prompts for an input.

**scanf()**

```
 scanf("%d, %d", &num1, &num2);
```

Unless you wrote it intentionally `','` and space (`' '`) are redundant. If that's the case  `scanf()` expects two integers to be seperated by a comma and a possible whitespace(s).

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But can you please explain how adding a space before `%c`  in  `scanf(" %c", &opr);` in  fixes the issue?

Comment: "If that's the case  scanf() expects two integers two be seperated with a comma and a possible whitespace(s)." The program is working in both the cases (with and without a space after a comma. It always does.

Comment: So basically adding a space will still work even if i don't have any newline character in the buffer?

Comment: yes, that's right. read man page of `scanf` for more info on its behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

`fflush(stdin);` is undefined behavior.

[Per the C Standard:](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **7.21.5.2  The `fflush` function**
>
> ...
>
> If `stream` points  to  an  output  stream  or  an  update  stream  in
>   which  the  most  recent operation was not input, the `fflush`
>   function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to
>   the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.**