# scanf gets stuck and keeps taking input

Tags: c, scanf

I was writing a simple sorting program but `scanf()` appears to be stuck and keeps taking infinite inputs. I know if I enter an invalid input this will happen. But, even when I enter `int` this occurs.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[5],temp,pos,i=0;
    printf("Enter the elements\n");

    while(i<5){
        scanf("%d ",&arr[i]);
        ++i;
    }

    printf("Sorted Array:");

    for(int i=0;i<4;++i){
        pos = i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<5;++i){
            if(arr[pos]>arr[j])
                pos = j;
        }

        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[pos];
        arr[pos] = temp;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(int j=i+1;j<5;++i){` : `++i` --> `++j` ,  `scanf("%d ",` --> `scanf("%d",`

Comment: That is why it's almost always a bad idea to use `scanf()` for user inputs!!

Comment: printf("Sorted Array:\n"); <-- make this and you'll see why

Comment: for scanf problem, a good explanation is given at: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306659/the-program-doesnt-stop-on-scanfc-ch-line-why)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your code isn't about the `scanf()`. It is due to improper loops constraints.

```
for(int i=0;i<4;++i){
       pos = i;
         for(int j=i+1;j<5;++i){
             if(arr[pos]>arr[j])
                pos = j;
        }
         temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[pos];
        arr[pos] = temp;

    }
```

The above sorting loop is the reason for your problem. You have to change `++i` in inner loop to `++j` which will solve your issue.!!

```
for(int i=0;i<4;++i){
       pos = i;
         for(int j=i+1;j<5;++j){
             if(arr[pos]>arr[j])
                pos = j;
        }
         temp = arr[i];
         arr[i] = arr[pos];
        arr[pos] = temp;

    }
```

You can correct the code like this.! Hope this helps.!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you had minor typo mistake, 
changes ++i to ++j in sorting inner loop will solve the problem.