# Immediate duplicate char finder program

Tags: c, arrays, char

My program is to find out if in the input any char is immediate repeated.For example

> input::
>
> 5
>
> RRRRR
>
> expected output::
>
> 4

**as R repeated 4 times**

but given output is 2

I have tried with 2 different program.But output seems to be same.

**First tried program**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char input[51];

    int n, i, count=0;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&input[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(input[i]==input[i-1])
            count++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

**2nd tried Program**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a, b;

    int n, i, count=0;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf("%c",&a);

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&b);
        if(a==b)
            count++;
        else
            a=b;
    }

    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

**Here n is the number of char to be entered**.So can anyone help me to findout where i am going wrong?

Comment: `scanf("%c",&b);` -->`scanf(" %c",&b);` note space before `%c`.

Comment: I suspect [one of many, many, *many* duplicates is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306659/the-program-doesnt-stop-on-scanfc-ch-line-why)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The program doesn't stop on scanf("%c", &ch) line, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306659/the-program-doesnt-stop-on-scanfc-ch-line-why)

Comment: thanks @kiranBiradar i did it  and it seems worked out,.Can u tell me why it worked?when i **scanf("%c",&b); -->scanf(" %c",&b);** did this?

Answer (score 1):

I got it, whenever we use scanf and at last of input, we use **"ENTER"**.**but the "%c" in second scanf takes it as input**.so in upper problem my program should be
**1st program**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char input[51];

    int n, i, count=0;

    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %c",&input[i]);
    }

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(input[i]==input[i-1])
            count++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

**2nd Program**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a, b;

    int n, i, count=0;

    scanf("%d",&n);
    scanf(" %c",&a);

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %c",&b);
        if(a==b)
        {
            count++;
        }
        else
            a=b;
    }

    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

**In above all program notice %c is placed with a heading space.**