# How to input eof(Ctrl+z) while letting the scanf have a space before the specifier to avoid getting previous \n error?

Tags: c, input, scanf, eof, feof

[image]

( I hit enter)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int target,result;
    while(1){
        printf("Please input your target: ");
        scanf(" %d",&target);
        if(feof(stdin)){
            break;
        }
        printf("test\n");       
    }
}
```

if I chnage the code to: (delete the space)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int target,result;
    while(1){
        printf("Please input your target: ");
        scanf("%d",&target);//no space
        if(feof(stdin)){
            break;
        }
        printf("test\n");       
    }
}
```

it worked

[image]

Comment: You don't need space before `%d`, since it always skips over whitespace to read a number.

Comment: but scanf("%s",a); saves \n in the caches

Comment: That's OK. As I said, `%d` skips over whitespace, and `\n` is whitespace.

Comment: what if now it's not %d but %s, then the eof can be detected with space added before %s?

Comment: `%s` also skips over whitespace to read one word.

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf()` to tell if it read anything.

Comment: there's reason to add space before %, but I forgot it

Comment: You need it before certain formats, like `%c` because they don't skip whitespace automatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306659/the-program-doesnt-stop-on-scanfc-ch-line-why

Comment: Please don't post images of text; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors