# I made a quiz game but it always prints 'wrong' even if the input is correct

Tags: c

After every question my program is asking for the answer but it's always printing "wrong" even if the answer is right, after reviewing my code i think it's probably coming from the first or the second for loop.

THIS IS THE FIRST QUESTION

```
QUIZ GAME !
------------------------------------
.1 What year did the C language debut ? :
A. 1969
B. 1972
C. 1965
D. 1999
guess: b
Wrong!
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char questions[][100] = {".1\\ What year did the C language debut ? : ",
                             ".2\\ Who is credited with creating C ? : ",
                             ".3\\ what is the predecessor of C ? : "};

    char options[][100] = {"A. 1969", "B. 1972", "C. 1965", "D. 1999",
                           "A. Dennis Ritchie", "B. Nikola Teala", "C. John Carmack", "D. Doc Brown",
                           "A. Objective C", "B. B", "C. C++", "D. C#"};

    char answers[3] = {'B', 'A', 'B'};
    int numberOFquestions = sizeof(questions) / sizeof(questions[0]);

    char guess;
    int score;
    score = 0;

    printf("QUIZ GAME !\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOFquestions; i++)
    {
        printf("------------------------------------\n");
        printf("%s\n", questions[i]);

        for (int j = (i * 4); j < (i * 4) + 4; j++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", options[j]);
        }

        printf("guess: ");
        scanf("%c", &guess);
        scanf("%c"); // second scanf helps clear \n from the input buffer

        // accept lowercase answers
        guess = toupper(guess);

        if (guess == answers[i])
        {
            printf("Correct!\n");
            score++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong!\n");
        }
    }

    printf("**********************\n");
    printf("FINAL SCORE: %d/%d\n", score, numberOFquestions);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
        scanf("%c"); // second scanf helps clear \n from the input buffer
```

The `%c` format operator requires a variable to write the character into. Since you didn't provide a variable, undefined behavior occurred.

Instead of clearing the newline from the input buffer, use

```
        scanf(" %c", &guess);
```

when reading the guess. The space at the beginning tells it to skip over any whitespace before reading a character, and this will skip over the newline from the previous answer. See [The program doesn't stop on scanf("%c", &ch) line, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306659/the-program-doesnt-stop-on-scanfc-ch-line-why)

If you do want to remove the newline, you could just use `getchar()` to read a character from stdin and discard it. Or use the `*` modifier in the format string to extract a character and ignore it instead of writing to a variable

```
        scanf("%*c"); // second scanf helps clear \n from the input buffer
```

Comment: These are all good suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Your program starts working when you remove the part that causes [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20undefined%20behavior,which%20the%20computer%20code%20adheres.):

```
scanf("%c"); // second scanf helps clear \n from the input buffer
```

Causes undefined behavior because you didn't provide a variable to place the input from `scanf`.

Fixing that line makes you program work as inteded:

```
char tmp;
scanf("%c", &tmp); // second scanf helps clear \n from the input buffer
```

Also, using `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` you would be able to get such information without asking on stackoverflow:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic input.c

input.c:35:17: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat-insufficient-args]
        scanf("%c"); // second scanf helps clear \n from the input buffer
```

**ALWAYS** compile with `-Wall` (and friends) they can catch quite a lot of common errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` should be given a variable, the variable would be able to accept the correct input.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).