Logic error of string input and output in C
I used Visual Studio.
The purpose of this code is to print the value that comes out when the received character arrangement is read vertically.
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    char a[5][15] = { 0, };
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
            scanf("%c", &a[i][j]); 
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%c", a[j][i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

input
AABCDD
afzz
09121
a8EWg6
P5h3kx

Expected Output
Aa0aPAf985Bz1EhCz2W3D1gkD6x

Real Output -> It doesn't print something.
I don't know why it isn't work on my purpose.
Please, explain for me.

Try adding a printf("\n") at the end to flush stdout.

@Mureinik Output is automatically flushed when the program exits.

If you print %c as a whole value when you finish the first nested for loop but before the second one what comes out?

Note that you're not skipping over the newline characters when you read input. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306659/the-program-doesnt-stop-on-scanfc-ch-line-why

Your input loop tries to read 75 characters. But you're only entering 32 characters. So there's no output because it's still waiting for the rest of the input.

Also some lines have 5 characters others have 6. So your skipping some inputs.

Why are you reading in each line of input character by character rather than using fgets?

scanf("%c") is really not the best way to spell getchar.  scanf is full of sharp edges and odd behavior; it is best to avoid it until you understand it better.  At which point you will avoid it because you understand it better.

Your code will try to fill all of the characters in your 5x15 array. You need to stop filling a line as soon as you see an end-of-line character:
    for (j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        char c;
        scanf("%c", &c);
        if (c == '\n')
            break;
        else
            a[i][j] = c;
    }

This is just to get you started. You should debug your code and fix the other problems.

Nice clear first step.  Next: testing the return value of scanf() is useful too.

Doing a compilation of all the things you can do to improve it. This comes from the comments below the question.

Various columns have between 4 and 6 characters while only expecting 15 characters when reading a column. You need to make sure it is standardized. Row two (2) has 4 characters, the third (3) row has 5 characters and rows one (1), four (4), five (5) have 6 characters. This means that there will likly leave null values in those positions.

As the user Barmur link in the comments to another question shows, when using scanf() in C you need to add an infront of '%c'. It should look as follows scanf(" %c", a[j][i]); This will have it stop at the end of line and skip any spaces that exist.


Edit:
The code given by anatolyg is another solid solution to the second problem that I had mentioned above. You can use either solution.
Edit 2:
Eric made me realize that I confused which values was being used for rows vs columns. Updated the values so that it showed the correct ones.

Re “… you need to add an infront of '%c'… This will have it stop at the end of line and skip any spaces that exist”: Whether a program needs to use a space before %c depends on what we want the program to do. It is not correct in this case because it will not stop at the end of the line. A newline character qualifies as a white-space character, so using  %c with scanf will make the program unable to see where lines end.

Re “you only expect 5 values when reading a row”: The program attempts to read 15 characters per row, not 5.

For the first comment. Makes sense. I was basing myself off of the post Barmar had linked as I only have a basic understanding of how scanf works.

For the second comment, I was reading as 15 for the column and the 5 as the row. But you would still be primarily correct. Its trying to read 15 characters and reciving between 4-6 characters.

"scanf(" %c", a[j][i]); This will have it stop at the end of line and skip any spaces that exist." --> No.  The " " will consume the end-of-line and any spaces is true, yet when the 5th line of input occurs, scanf(" %c", a[j][i]); will not return, instead waiting for some non-white-space.
